# How to access a Q_ENUM declared in C++ class from QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qenum

I have a `Q_ENUM` declared in `MyClass` like below:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    enum Enum_Test {
        eTestA,
        eTestB
    }
    Q_ENUM(Enum_Test)

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyClass::Enum_Test enumTest READ GetEnumTest WRITE SetEnumTest )
}
```

I have `MyClass` registered on the QML side like below and able to access it.

```
auto my_class = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1,0, "MyClass","Cannot create type MyClass in QML");
rootContext()->setContextProperty("my_class", my_class.get());
```

How do I access `Q_ENUM Enum_Test` from QML?

Comment: The shown piece of code is not how you _register_ a class, this is setting a context property. You need `qmlRegisterType` after which you can do `MyClass.TestA`. Also the enum _must_ start with a capital

Comment: I updated my question. If I get an example of how to access the Q_ENUM which is the primary point of my question, I can take care of registering the class properly.

Comment: MyClass should be derived from a QObject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your class needs two adjustments.

1. as pointed out by JarMan, it needs a metaObject, which can be obtained by deriving from QObject and adding Q_OBJECT:

   ```
   class MyClass : public QObject
   {
       Q_OBJECT
       ...
   };
   ```

   Actually, it would also be possible to use `Q_GADGET` but you already seem to lean towards `Q_OBJECT`. But, as requested, here we go:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
     Q_GADGET

   public:
     enum Enum_Test {
         ETestA,
         ETestB
     };
     Q_ENUM(Enum_Test)
   };
   ```

   Keep in mind that Q_GADGET [cannot have signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_GADGET), so I left out the property and only have this class as "enum-placeholder".
2. The enum value names need to be capitalized:

   ```
   enum Enum_Test {
       ETestA,
       ETestB
   };
   Q_ENUM(Enum_Test)
   ```

Then you can use it in QML as:

```
     QtObject {
         property int myEnumVal: MyClass.ETestA
     }
```

Note that support for enums is somewhat limited because the mix with JavaScript. The values will be converted to integers. Also, when used in a JavaScript switch-statement, typo's will not be warned about by QtCreator (assuming version 4.14)

Comment: Thanks. I am accepting this. It would be nice to show the `Q_GADGET` based example and I can accept it. Do you mind editing your answer using `Q_GADGET`?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer No problem, I have added it

Comment: In my case, "constexpr is not valid here" error in this example because there is no semicolon for definition ```Enum_Test```. I used Visual Studio 2019 and Qt 5.15. What's the difference?

Comment: @WOOSEOKCHOI That is probably an error in my post, will edit

Comment: The class does need to get registered through qmlRegisterType or something. So how do you do that with a Q_GADGET ? And can it work with an abstract class too ?

Comment: It is the same as in the OP, plus `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>("MyClass")`. I think the question of abstract does not relate to the original answer, so please create a new question for that (apart from that, quick test shows that it seems not to compile)

Answer (score 5):

The answer provided by @Amfasis is already good. As I tend to do this pretty often, I wrote a little shortcut for defining enums with all the features Qt offers, including the availability in QML here: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils#lqtutils_enumh.

You only need to include the header, define your enum values like:

```
L_DECLARE_ENUM(Enum_Test,
    ETestA,
    ETestB
)
```

and register it where you prefer with:

```
Enum_Test::qmlRegisterMySharedEnum("some.uri", 1, 0);
```

Also this uses simple namespaces, which is lighter than using QObjects or gadgets.

Actually, I got used to always declare my enums like this when I'm using Qt, because I can also benefit from [QMetaEnum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaenum.html). For instance, I really like to be able to log like this:

```
qDebug() << "Value:" << Enum_Test::ETestA;
```

getting:

```
Value: Enum_Test::ETestA
```

instead of a simple integer.

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks for posting this answer even after there was an accepted one.